# Передача значения при нажатии на контекстное меню QAction

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, сигналы-слоты

При срабатывании `QACtion` на лэйбле с содержимым хочу передавать его содержимое(`i` в моём примере) в аргумент функции, которая срабатывает на `QAction.triggered.connect`.

Получалось только через `elf.sender().text()`, но для этого нужно было в `QAction` вставлять это самое содержимое.

Как можно передать в `triggered.connect` аргумент text для функции?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)


        for i in range(10):
            label = QLabel()
            label.setText(str(i))

            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
            print_action = QAction('Принтануть', self)
            print_action.triggered.connect(self.print_label_text)
            label.addAction(print_action)

            self.vbox.addWidget(label)


        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.area.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)

    def print_label_text(self, text):
        print(text)
        print('success')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [signal]void QAction::triggered(bool checked = false)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается, когда действие активируется пользователем; например, когда пользователь щелкает опцию меню, кнопку на панели инструментов или нажимает сочетание клавиш действия, или когда вызывался trigger(). Примечательно, что он не генерируется при вызове setChecked() или toggle().
>
> Если действие является проверяемым, флажок true, если действие проверено, или false, если действие не отмечено.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea

class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)


        for i in range(10):
            label = QLabel()
            label.setText(str(i))

            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
            print_action = QAction('Принтануть', self)
            
#            print_action.triggered.connect(self.print_label_text)
            print_action.triggered.connect(lambda ch, text=label.text(): self.print_label_text(text))
            
            label.addAction(print_action)

            self.vbox.addWidget(label)

        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.resize(self.width(), self.height())
        self.area = QWidget()
        self.area.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(self.area)

    def print_label_text(self, text):
        print(text)
        print('success')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо, то что нужно.